# What is a macro in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macros

I was reading the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), and I have encountered the term `macros`.
I can't find the definition of the term (in the context of Rails).
Can someone point me to a place where the term is defined?

I am familiar with the term in a different context as a software for "recording" actions (mouse, keyboard actions in OS, for instance).
Is there any connection between the different uses of the term?

Answer (score 5):

In this context, a macro is a piece of code that generates some other code. For example:

```
attr_accessor :foo
```

generates this:

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(val)
  @foo = val
end
```

> Is there any connection between the different uses of the term?

Kind of. You could say that author of `attr_accessor` "recorded" what it should expand to.

Comment: There is no such thing as “ruby macros.” These hipsters from Rails world are just weak in naming :-P

Comment: @mudasobwa: depends on your definition of "macro" :)

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby a macro is like a method, just some code, that instead of returning a Ruby datatype returns more Ruby code! This code will get executed along with all the other code you have written when you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with @Sergio as he explained **'A macro is a piece of code that generates some other code.'**
In example he explained:

```
attr_accessor :foo
```

Here `attr_accessor` is a macro that is generating some code automatically and we do not write this complete code.

I want to explain this with a simple example:

If you work in a large application with **thousands of routes**, a single **config/routes.rb** file can become cumbersome and hard to read because you will define all **thousands of routes** here.

So the solution is:

**Step 1:** We should define all routes in separate files inside the config directory.

**Step 2:** We will use `draw` macro to generate all file routes in routes.rb like mention below:

[image: draw macro is using in routes file]