# How is method being called outside of Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coming from the PHP world and I'm specifically looking at the [Act As Votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem but it may apply to anything in Ruby. I don't understand that you can add `acts_as_votable` method to your class when it is in a Module.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
end
```

I would expect `ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable::acts_as_votable`.  What allows this to be run without calling the modules?

Comment: TL;DR: the gem adds that method to your class – you merely call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first add `acts_as_votable` gem it extends `ActiveRecord::Base` with methods defined in `ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable` module, its pretty common pattern to use modules as mixins [mixins](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html).

This initialization is done with this line:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable
```

in [lib/acts_as_votable.rb](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_votable.rb) file

in other words methods inside `ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable` will be available as class methods to `ActiveRecord::Base` along with its inheritance chain.

the `acts_as_votable` in the post model is the execution of the method defined in the `Votable` module, which usually called a macro. It's a class method that defines another instance methods in that model. It has the same idea behind the `has_many`, `belongs_to`, .... macros.

[macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321398/what-is-a-macro-in-rails)

[extend](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/extend)

Comment: It kind of makes sense but `ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable` is inside the `ActsAsVotable` module. How is that loaded automatically?

Comment: Tbh, I don't fully understand your question. If you mean how Rails is aware of ActsAsVotable files, it's [Bundler](https://bundler.io/). You can read more here https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-does-rails-handle-gems/

Answer (score 2):

at [act_as_votable.rb](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_votable.rb) is where the magic happens. at line 13 you can see `ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable`. `extend` method here will inject `ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable` methods into ActiveRecord::Base class methods.

since Post inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` which has `ActsAsVotable` module methods injected as class methods, Post can call `acts_as_votable` directly.

Answer (score 2):

When module is loaded, it is extended to `ActiveRecord::Base`: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/599995f7ec5aa0f8a04312768fc956e9003d32d4/lib/acts_as_votable.rb

so, methods in module are available as class methods of `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

For more info about include/extend, you can check the article here:

https://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Comment: Thanks, now it makes better sense. I am seeing ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable is inside the ActsAsVotable module. Does that module get loaded automatically?

Answer (score 2):

> What allows this to be run without calling the modules?

It works because:

- Ruby uses `self` if you don't specify an explicit receiver
- the class body is evaluated in the context of your class (`self` is `Post`)
- your `Post` class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`
- the gem adds `acts_as_votable` as a *class method* to `ActiveRecord::Base`

When you write:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
end
```

it basically means:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.acts_as_votable
end
```

which is actually:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  Post.acts_as_votable
end
```

which could be rewritten as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Post.acts_as_votable
```

The above isn't specific to the gem. Within the class body, you can call any of your class' *class methods* directly. You might know:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

That's not some special keyword – [`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is a regular (class) method. The same applies to all the Rails DSL methods like `has_many`, `validates` or `after_save`.